# How to replace string between two others and remove last 5 characters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that will allow me to manipulate some URLs in order to quickly switch between content editing views and production in a new CMS.

Currently, I am able to replace the begging string of the URL with the CMS version, which is great.  However, I also need to be able to remove the ".html" at the end of the string, which is what I'm struggling with.

**WHAT I HAVE NOW**

The following is my current bookmarklet:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){window.location=window.location.toString
().replace(/^http(.*)\/en\//,'https://cms.ca/en_lg/').replace(/^https:(.*)
\/fr\//,'https://cms.ca/fr_lg/');})();">Switch - CMS</a>
```

With the above bookmarklet, I can do the following (I removed the 'h' at the front since they're not real links.):

CHANGE THIS:

- ttp://www.webby.yay.com/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html

TO THIS:

- ttps://cms.ca/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

CHANGE THIS:

- ttp://www.webby.yay.com/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html"

TO THIS:

- ttps://cms.ca/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page

Notice that the **.html** at the end of the string has been removed.

Is this possible to do with one replace method?  If so, could I also combine the fact that I check for either /en_lg/ or /fr_lg/ into one expression?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can merge those two or maybe three replace methods into one using capturing groups:

```
window.location.toString().replace(/^http:\/\/.*?\/(en|fr)(.*?)(\.\w+)?$/, 'https://cms.ca/$1_lg$2')
```

Demo:

```js
var url = "http://www.webby.yay.com/en/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html"
console.log(url.replace(/^http:\/\/.*?\/(en|fr)(.*?)(\.\w+)?$/, 'https://cms.ca/$1_lg$2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to simply ignore /en_lg/ and /fr_lg/:

`.replace(/^http:\/\/www.webby.yay.com\/(.*)\.html$/,'https://cms.ca/$1')`

eg:

`"http://www.webby.yay.com/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html".replace(/^http:\/\/www.webby.yay.com\/(.*)\.html$/,'https://cms.ca/$1')`

gives

`"https://cms.ca/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.  I should have been clearer, but the string I am trying to replace can range a variety of different things.
For example,  I could get a URL like ttp://www.webby.yay.com/en_lg/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder/page.html or ttp://whatisthis.com/fr_lg/folder/example/anotherfolder/test.html or ttp://www.iamnotasite.hi.coolstuffbro.com/fr_lg/cool/cool.html.  I basically want to replace everything between http until fr_lg or en_lg and then remove the html at the end.

Comment: How about `.replace(/^(.*)\/(en_lg|fr_lg)\/(.*)\.html$/,'https://cms.ca/$2/$3')` ?